# USB Condenser mic with Nexus 10 tablet

Tags: usb, microphone, samsung-nexus-10

I've got a Samsung / Google Nexus 10 tablet, and I'd like to find a way to use my AudioTechnica AT2020 USB condenser microphone with it. The microphone has a standard USB type B connector on it (similar to a printer), and the typical cable goes to a USB type A connector.

Does anyone know if there is any way to hook this up, so I can record audio with my tablet?

Comment: I don't think the OS supports USB audio, so you'd need to find a custom ROM and kernel that do.